# python eve sqlalchemy dont create table schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eve

Im starting with python Eve and I copied the example exactly from here: http://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/trivial.html

and I'm getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQoYU.png

It seems like it can create the table schema but it can connect to the database

This example is working with SQLite, I tried also with MySQL and I'm getting the same error (I already created the table).

Any hints?

Comment: What is the query you're trying to run? Can you add the SQL alchemy query and how you constructed it?

Comment: No query, is the exact same code of the example link, but simply the decorator is not creating the scheme, and it fails  because theres no table in the database :(

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such error in my setup. But the problem usually went away after I :

1. Delete the sqlite file
2. Restart the development server